# Joda DateTimeFormatter garbage collection

Tags: jodatime

I’m using Joda time API and I ran the profiler to inspect the heap. I see a lot of org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter instances around 60 of them not being gc’ed.  I create a single instance of the DateTimeFormatter and reuse it every time for creating DateTime objects within a method.

Does anyone know why these instances are not being garbage collected?